# Javascript Optimization : issue on V8 and on IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, optimization, v8

I'm currentyl trying to optimize my game engine written in Javascript. i'm running into many issues but here is 2 that are leaving me a bit clueless.

I've got a class that represents the player's unit in my game. The player has 4 units, all created at the start of the game.

I'm using something very simple, kinda like that :

```
function PartyCharacter()
{
this.Armor ;
this.FireResistance ;
this.CriticalStrike ;
// a hundred more like that
}
```

I was thinking that having property value un-initialized wasnt very safe / good design and that it potentially could hurt javascript optimization regarding the type of the variable so I assigned them a basic value :

```
function PartyCharacter()
{
this.Armor = 0 ;
this.FireResistance = 0 ;
this.CriticalStrike = 0 ;
// a hundred more like that
}
```

It gave me a small performance boost on firefox but it gave me a 300% decrease in overall performance on chrome. I'm having a hard time figuring out what it causing it. The only thing I noticed is that the performance drop happens after a certain number of variable initialisation (something like 15 or so). if I initialize only 14, the performance stays "normal". As soon as add one more " = 0", the performance drop and drop hard.

I've checked chrome profiler and the issue seems to be that it now faling to optimize other function in the code (too many optimization on the function). The 2 function that are concerned by this newly V8 optimization issue do not interact directly with the Player's unit but they do call other functions that do.
I've tried --trace on the V8 but as I'm on widnows it was a pain just to redirect the stdout to a consonle windows and the windows doesnt allow copy/paste and is too spammy to be readable and get info there.

I'm a bit clueless about that behavior.

Likewise I tought about declaring these variables as protoype since all instances of Player's unit use them. It gave me a 20% performance drop on both FF and Chrome. I cannot figure out why is that.

If that can help : I access these variable A LOT and change their value a lot too.

```
function PartyCharacter()
{

}
PartyCharacter.prototype.Armor = 0 ;
PartyCharacter.prototype.FireResistance = 0 ;
PartyCharacter.prototype.CriticalStrike = 0 ;
```

Another thing that is currently eluding me is the difference of performance i got between browsers. FF/Chrome are about the same but IE specifically is always 3 times slower.

I've tried to profile the game for 60 seconds and see if there was any bottle-neck on IE but, looking at the profiling results alone, I would think that IE is faster O_o I must be missing something.

I know FF (using firebug atm) and IE's profiler works a bit differently but I can't explain the results of my profiling session.

On both session the ratio of number of functions calls is the same. So the game logic is not impacted on IE and only the time spent inside function should explain the speed difference.

I see that on IE i've got 2 functions with a much higher "self" time (not including function called inside) than their counterpart on FF: 33%+17% on IE and 7%+2% and FF.

The issue is that the average time for these functions are shorter on IE than on FF.

That means that function that are called the same number of time on both browser, execute faster on IE but at the same times takes much more time of the overall game process? Something is wrong, somwhere....but I can't put my finger on what is it.

Here is a pastebin for my profiling data for FF : http://pastebin.com/sjxWaz6p#

Same thing for IE : http://pastebin.com/9NW1E0bg#

Copy/paste the raw data in excel and your' good to go !

Comment: Adding "too many" properties hurts optimizations in chrome. V8 has two object representation modes and having more than a certain number causes it to deoptimize. In general though - assigning values _is_ faster than not doing so in v8.

Comment: Like Benjamin says. To be more precise, if an object has many properties, Chrome automatically uses a hash table instead of a struct. If you want to keep using structs, you'd have to split your object's properties into several objects (e.g. `this.resistances.fire` instead of `this.fireResistance`).

Comment: Thx for the answerson that first part! In the end, even if they are not initialized right away, my objects all have all the listed properties. Does it means that if I initialize the property outside the constructor (what I'm currently doing), v8 will optimize as a hash ? Why doesnt he do that if I initialize them in the constructor ? In both cases, during my code, my object have the exact same number of variable and yet in one case it is optimized and in the other not. Im a bit confused :)

Comment: @Touffy slightly different rules apply to constructors as opposed to normal property addition. V8 actually counts number of assignments of form `this.propname` inside a constructor and adjusts "too many properties" limit for an object accordingly (within certain bounds). E.g. with the most recent V8 `function foo() { this.f0 = 0; /* ... */ this.f500 = 0; }` constructs fast (i.e. not-hash table) object *when used as constructor* `new foo()`. 

But if you are using something like `obj = {}; foo.call(obj);` then it would go slow case.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, initializing fields in your constructor definitely makes sense, and should lead to performance improvements. Your first snippet (`function PartyCharacter() { this.Armor ; ...`) doesn't create any fields. It *reads* the `.Armor` field, which isn't present, so the read returns `undefined`; it does *not* change the object in any way; and V8 doesn't take this as a hint that the property will be created later either.

The slowdown you're seeing when initializing those fields *might* be due to different types being stored in them. V8 does some amount of type tracking for class fields, but that can lead to performance costs when those types change late in execution. Will all the values that are stored later be integers? Will they be doubles? Will they be strings/booleans/objects? Try initializing the fields to `undefined` (if they'll store objects later; or `NaN` if they're number-only) and see if that helps.

Initializing properties on the prototype is not going to help if you're going to overwrite them later (because those writes won't go to the prototype, they'll create fields on the objects themselves). On the other hand, if they're "constants" (i.e. never changed), then storing them on the prototype is the most memory-efficient way to keep them.

(I know nothing about other browsers so I can't help with the questions referring to FF/IE.)